# How to replace a specific character in a file, only on the lines by counting this specific character in the line?

Tags: terminal, command, command-line-interface, text-processing

I would like **to double the 4th comma in the lines counting 7 and only 7 commas** in all the csv's of a folder.

In this command line, I double the 4th comma:

```
sed  's/,/,,/4' Person_7.csv > new.csv
```

In this command line, I can find and count all the commas in a line:

```
sed 's/[^,]//g' dat | awk '{ print length }'
```

In this command line, I can count and create a new file with lines containing 7 commas:

```
awk -F , 'NF == 7' <Person_test.csv >Person_7.csv
```

But I don't know how to do the specific work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to select only the lines that contain exactly 7 commas and then operate on just these lines. You can do that with sed:

```
sed '/^\([^,]*,\)\{7\}[^,]*$/s/,/&&/4'
```

where `^\([^,]*,\)\{7\}[^,]*$` defines a line that contains exactly 7 commas.

It's a bit easier with awk, though:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NF == 8 { $4 = $4 OFS } 1'
```

This sets input and output field separators to `,`, and then for lines with 8 fields (7 commas) appends a `,` to the end of the 4th field, doubling the comma. The final `1` makes sure every line gets printed.